# TypeError: token must be bytes when it is already bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

So, here's my code:

```py
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

def decrypt_data(key, data):
    key = bytes(key.encode('utf-8'))
    SALT = b'\xbf\xd4\xa9\xcei\xfa\xa7Db\x83\xbf\xa5.\xbe/\xd9'

    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=SALT,
        iterations=32000
    )
    fernet = Fernet(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(key)))
    return fernet.decrypt(data)

def encrypt_data(key, data):
    key = bytes(key.encode('utf-8'))
    SALT = b'\xbf\xd4\xa9\xcei\xfa\xa7Db\x83\xbf\xa5.\xbe/\xd9'

    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=SALT,
        iterations=32000
    )

    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(key))
    fernet = Fernet(key)
    return fernet.encrypt(data.encode())
```

Here's the full code (get_history fetches the encrypted data, and decrypts it with a key)

```py
from cryptography.fernet import InvalidToken
from framework.local_storage_encryption import encrypt_data, decrypt_data

# get_history() ->
# -1: unknown exception
# 0: success
# 1: invalid key

def get_history(key):
    try:
        value = []
        string_plain = decrypt_data(key, open('local_storage/HISTORY').readlines())
        for url in string_plain.split("\n"):
            value.append(url)
        return value
    except InvalidToken as exc:
        print(f"[!!!] Unable to load search history as the decryption key provided is invalid.")
        return [], 1

    return [], -1

def save_history(key, value: list):
    string_plain = ""
    for url in value:
        string_plain += f"{url}\n"

    with open('local_storage/HISTORY', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(encrypt_data(key, string_plain))

history = get_history("test") # this function itself raises the error
```

for some reason, encryption works just fine, but when it comes to decryption, it throws this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trayambak/Projects/Browser/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/trayambak/Projects/Browser/main.py", line 15, in main
    window.init()
  File "/home/trayambak/Projects/Browser/framework/__init__.py", line 41, in init
    self.live_history = get_history(encryption_key)
  File "/home/trayambak/Projects/Browser/framework/history_reader.py", line 12, in get_history
    string_plain = decrypt_data(key, open('local_storage/HISTORY').readlines())
  File "/home/trayambak/Projects/Browser/framework/local_storage_encryption.py", line 18, in decrypt_data
    return fernet.decrypt(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 76, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 101, in _get_unverified_token_data
    utils._check_bytes("token", token)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 33, in _check_bytes
    raise TypeError("{} must be bytes".format(name))
TypeError: token must be bytes
```

(no, the key isn't randomly generated every execution, I use the key 'testing', this isn't a salt problem either)

As you can see, the key is very much encoded into `bytes` yet cryptography throws this error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. The only sketch thing that can cause an error here in my opinion is `PBKDF2HMAC`, but it worked earlier, but now it does not. The key is a `str` converted to `bytes`, hence I am very confused.

Comment: Not reproducible. Post the complete code. By the way, a static salt is insecure.

Comment: Alright. Wait a minute.

Comment: Done, also, will fix the static salt thing.

Comment: This is not an encryption problem, but simply an I/O and encoding issue. Just debug it. Try in `get_history()` something like `string_plain = decrypt_data(key, open('local_storage/HISTORY', 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')`.